# Infinite loop protection

Tags: javascript, infinite-loop, esprima

I'm working on JavaScript code editor where users can write their own JavaScript code in the browser and run it. I need to find a way to break out of infinite loops. When I am given the code:

```
while (1) {
    doSomething();
}
```

I want to transform the code to something like this:

```
var start = Date.now();
while (1) {
    if (Date.now() - start > 1000) { break; }
    doSomething();
}
```

I stumbled upon Web-Maker, [which has a function that does exactly this](https://github.com/chinchang/web-maker/blob/master/src/utils.js#L108). I couldn't get the function to transform the code passed in. I've tried `addInfiniteLoopProtection('while (1) doSomething()', { timeout: 1000 })` but it returns `'while (1) doSomething()'` instead of changing the code to break out of the infinite loop.

[Here's my attempt on codepen](https://codepen.io/SummerJacket/pen/XGNOOB)

Answer (score 1):

I found [loop-protect](https://github.com/jsbin/loop-protect). Install Babel standalone and loop-protect through npm:

```
npm i @babel/standalone loop-protect
```

Then add the JavaScript code:

```
import Babel from '@babel/standalone';
import protect from 'loop-protect';

const timeout = 100;
Babel.registerPlugin('loopProtection', protect(timeout));

const transform = source => Babel.transform(source, {
  plugins: ['loopProtection'],
}).code;
```

`transform('while (1) doSomething()')` returns the string:

```
var _LP = Date.now();

while (1) {
  if (Date.now() - _LP > 100) break;
  doSomething();
}
```

Comment: instead of this shouldn't you be monitoring the thread for resource consumption? what if the user wants to run an infinite loop with low consumption(like pinging a website periodically), your compiler will completely disallow that usecase - or make a savvy user use recursive loops instead